# Do ACS and RSC journals have identical credit in a tenure-track application?

Tags: publications, faculty-application, tenure-track, chemistry

I am a postdoc in chemistry and have published 15 papers in RSC journals. I hope to publish about 8 papers during the next year and then apply for a tenure-track position in the US.

My group leader strongly prefers RSC journals. Both ACS and RSC have similar titles. As I compared, they publish similar numbers of papers with similar impact factors.

Since I want to apply for a position in the US, is it beneficial for me to publish some papers in the ACS journals or it is OK to have all my publications in the RSC journals?

ACS: American Chemical Society
RSC: Royal Society of Chemistry (UK)

Comment: They are not identical but very similar.

Comment: I would say that it never hurts to spread the papers around a bit. It exposes you to a broader community (while similar the two do not overlap perfectly), and that would be a good thing particularly if you are interested in the different geographic area. And, once here, don't just publish in ACS but continue to be more broad.

Comment: If it's a good paper, it doesn't matter much where you publish it: the work will be recognize whether it's ACS or RCS.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero In a job application, the search committee does not read the papers, they look at journals in the list of publications. At least for shortlisting, the journal titles are more important than the paper contents.

Comment: @All _In a job application, the search committee does not read the papers_ — Mine does.  (In particular, I do, and I'm not the only one.)

Comment: @JeffE 1. How do you manage to read the papers by hundreds or at least tens of applicants? If you read those of a few applicants, then, you have shortlisted them by the publication list first. 2. I have seen only a few job ads asking to upload sample works. How do you choose the sample papers of each candidate to read?

Comment: @All _you have shortlisted them by the publication list first_ -- ...and from recommendation letters from well-informed experts. -- _How do you choose the sample papers of each candidate to read?_ -- Recimmendation letters, Google Scholar, and whatever looks cool.

Comment: I think that you might put too much emphasis on this. In my sub-fields, both ACS and RSC publications are substantially equivalent. I see that your question is motivated by your desire to apply in US. Give a try to ACS then. But it might count little. By the way, what about an Angewande Chemie? :)

Answer (score 1):

Given reputable venues like these, you should expect a good department that you'd want to be a part of to pay attention to the substance of your work, rather than splitting hairs on whether they like one society better than the other.

Not all departments will do this, of course.  For example, I know of at least one department that discounts all journals except ones published by its favorite society.  Do you really want to be part of such a narrow institution, however?